# Is there a way to save an IMAP session in database

Tags: java, database, session, jakarta-mail, imap

I was wondering if there is anyway to save an IMAP session in database so that it can be reused.
Any help much appreciated

Darshan

Comment: What language, technology, what is your code?

Comment: What do you mean by "save an IMAP session"?  What exactly do you want to save?  All the IMAP protocol commands?  All the messages you accessed during the session?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: No.

An IMAP session is something which involves quite an involved amount of state of at least two networked services. The concept of caching a connection is very useful if you want to avoid a possible costly process of connection establishment, setup, configuration, and perhaps entering a particular state on the other end of the connection. With IMAP, this typically involves both setting up a TCP connection, agreeing upon an TLS session on top of that, exchanging authentication data, reading the remote party's `CAPABILITY` bits, exchanging the `ID` data for software version troubleshooting etc etc etc.

You *could* do something, for example it's quite possible to set up an IMAP proxy and design your DB-caching for using some identifiers-within-the-DB as a key/index/token for your proxy, but that sounds like a lot of work compared to what IMAP can do (and compared to what IMAP can easily benefit from, for example TLS session caching).

Have you tried IMAP command pipelining already? Have you measured and verified your performance data to see where the bottlenecks *really* are?

Comment: Thanks for spending your time in answering. Haven't tried with the IMAP command pipelining. Can you share a link that can be of some help to start with pipelining?